# Force iPad simulator to open to 100%

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

No matter what screen I'm on (17" 1920x1200) or 24", my iPad simulator ALWAYS opens to 50%, even if I recently opened and resized (Windows -> Scale -> 100%) on the last execution.

I can't find a way to always open to 100%. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Does your retina iPhone Simulator open in 100%?

Comment: So, the only way I see to get this to work is never "Quit" the simulator. Just leave it running in 100% and go back to code. On a control+r rebuild & launch it stays 100%.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change this behavior.  The iOS Simulator seems to size itself depending on the resolution of the monitor on which it appears.  I would consider filing a bug with Apple to make this a user preference.

Comment: Good point, perhaps I'll file a bug today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to force the iPad Simulator to open at 100%. You have to do it manually every time.

Comment: Right - if I leave the simulator open at 100% it works as I stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your display must be over a certain resolution for the Simulator to open at 100%.

Comment: Perhaps, however, I mentioned I have a 1920x1200 display...don't really know of many bigger resolutions (common).

Answer (score 1):

it must be something with new installations of Xcode.

I have my old iMac24" (1920x1200) on my desktop and iPad is running at 100% without window border. On my MBP (1680x1050) it keep launching in 50% mode with ugly window around it.

Comment: It has to do with the available space for the window. The dock settings (size and particularly auto-hide) affect how much of the screen can be used for windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting 50% at 1920x1080, and no border/window at 1920x1200.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard Shortcuts :

1. Command+1 = 100%
2. Command+2 = 75%
3. Command+3 = 50%

:)